# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject weird issue

Tags: windows-phone-8, json.net

I am facing some weird problem. Here is my response handler class

```
public class AdvisoryResponse
{
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string created_on { get; set; }
    public int profile_id { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

Here is code that de-serialize json string to object

```
string jsonStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
AdvisoryResponse res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AdvisoryResponse>(jsonStr);
```

Now here is jsonStr value for first time :

> {"category": "Crop", "text": "This is some msg", "created_on":
>   "07-08-2014 00:00:00", "id": 198513, "profile_id": 2947}

After de-serializing above string, I receive AdvisoryResponse object with profile_id = 2947

Here is jsonStr value at second time

> {"category": "Crop", "text": "This is some msg", "created_on":
>   "07-08-2014 00:00:00", "id": 198513, "profile_id": 2949}

After de-serializing above string, I receive the AdvisoryResponse object with profile_id = 2947 & not 2949.

Please help me to understand whats happening here

Thanks
Aniruddha

Comment: Change all the values of the second jsonStr.  If any of the other fields are the same, I'm guessing your await method is returning the same string as the first case.  Let me know thanks.

Comment: Cant do that. The line "string jsonStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();" its reading json content from server.

Comment: If you do as you described, define new string and response every time, then either you are getting the "wrong" string or you are changing the deserialized object's properties somewhere. No magic. Just debugging.

Comment: Maybe you are faceing some cache issues. If your download link is `"http://getjson.com/text"` try to replace that for something like `"http://getjson.com/text?guid=" + Guid.NewGuid()`

Comment: Suggestion gave by Andre is working. Also when I am calling JsonConvert.DeserializeObject, I am passing second parameter 'new JsonSerializerSettings()'.